# Why can the incoming call be always on top of screen?

Tags: screen, alarm

I want to implement an application that can be always on top of the screen, and can prevent the other app/dialog from covering my application.

For example,  the incoming call can be always on top of screen, even if the alarm clock is popping up at the same time, the alarm clock can't cover it.

What's the scheme about the function?  Thanks!

Comment: Always ask yourself the question, ***"what if two applications did this?"*** If it would blow up (or would be impossible), then chances are, it's impossible and you should reconsider your design.

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow. Since this is a general programming Q&A site where questions about *any* language and environment are on-topic, make sure to tag your question with information about your language and environment so people give you more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, it's logically impossible. What if the requirement of the alarm clock is "if there's an alarm, the alarm should always be displayed on the top of the screen, even if there's an incoming call"?

Read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx) for a much more detailed explanation of the logic. You'll find the code your writing will degenerate into a ticket stealing match:

> This is like saying, "Sometimes I'm in a hurry, and I want to make sure I am the next person to get served at the deli counter. To do this, I find whoever has the lowest number, knock them unconscious, and steal their ticket. But sometimes somebody else comes in who's also in a hurry. That person knocks me unconscious and steals my ticket."

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But the example I posed is a truth, because I have tried it.
And the link you pose is not android issue...

Comment: I make sure that no others will knock me unconscious..., I just want to know the reason "How can I knock someone unconscious"

Comment: Who said anything about Android? You haven't put anything in your question that says it's specific to Android. And it's certainly possible to make a window or notification topmost, but not *always* -- what if two notifications have to be always topmost?